# How to automatically let a sketch done in processing resize, when you resize a RCP window?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, processing

I am doing a project involving processing and RCP. I have done quite a bit of work thus far and would like to let my processing sketch automatically resize when I resize the RCP window (dragging the edge with the mouse).

Now a lot of websites says that resize is not supported in processing and some tell me to use frame.setResizable(true);. This returns an error when placed inside my `public void setup(){}` function.

My next optioon is to add a resize listener to the RCP window, but if I implement the code underneath, inside my main or createWindows function, it only returns errors.

Can someone please help me?

```
final Composite b = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);

b.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {

      public void handleEvent(Event e) {

        Tracker tracker = new Tracker(b.getParent(), SWT.RESIZE);
        tracker.setStippled(true);
        Rectangle rect = b.getBounds();
        tracker.setRectangles(new Rectangle[] { rect });
        if (tracker.open()) {
          Rectangle after = tracker.getRectangles()[0];
          b.setBounds(after);
        }
        tracker.dispose();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Those sites are right: Processing literally **does not support resizing**. It's not in the API, the only way you can do this is to use *not-Processing* code by escaping to the lowerlevel subsystem (if Java compiled, java JFrame resize handling, if JavaScript compiled, canvas/page resize handling). Naturally, doing so means you code is no longer Processing, and cannot be ported between environments that can run Processing code while guaranteeing the code will run (JS has no idea what Java is, and a java compile will break on JS syntax, for instance).

The Processing `size` function sets all kinds of administrative variables that cannot be set a second time without completely wrecking everything, and there is no separate `resize` function that we can make use of. Even more fun is that even if there was, 3D mode wouldn't let you do so because openGL/webGL resizing is impossible (all the GL buffers are fixed size, resizing would require a rebuild for each pixel of width/height change).

so if you want to be able to resize, do something clever instead, where you can make a new sketch that is instantiated with the state of the old sketch, so that you just pick up where you left off, in a new sketch instance.

Comment: Although my code below, i believe your solution should be better anyway, How would this sketch instance thing be done?

Comment: If you can serialize your state, you can give your sketch a function along the lines of `void setFullState(...) { ...}` and use that to rebuild; start a new sketch, tell sketch 1 that sketch 2 exists and have it communicate its state using `void notifyOfNewSketch(PApplat newSketch) { newSketch.setFullState(generateState()); }`. This is of course not trivial, being able to serialize/deserialise your state requires precision. If you target Java and/or JS specifically, there are better ways.

Comment: I figured it out :) Made added a actionListener to check for resizing and then just kind of redraw it. The only drawback is that i get a type of flickering. any ideas on how i might be able to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

Once I tried this, it seams to work, with OpenGL though its has some bugs, but kind of works also... look:
Of course you need to make resizable things relative to width/height...

```
void setup()
{
  size(200, 200);   // always first line
  frame.setResizable(true);
  background(255);
  smooth();
}


void draw()
{
  background(255);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, width/6, height/6);
}
```